# Comparing an object to the previous one in the array

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Afternoon Stack,

I'm relatively new to JS and knockout and I think I'm running into a simple issue.
I'm trying to separate the terms from each class and group them accordingly.

i.e.

W13

Adv Cptr Architecture (CPHE-533-A)

W14

Adv Database Systems (CPTR-521-A)

The object in the background is

```
"Classes": [
 {
  "FullName":"W13 Adv Cptr Architecture (CPHE-533-A)",
 --Irrelevant information
 },
 {
  "FullName": "W14 Adv Database Systems (CPTR-521-A)",
 --Irrelevant information
 }
 ]
```

My call to knockout is

```
 <ul class="myclasses-container" data-bind="foreach: myclasses.Classes">
 <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
<p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:16px" data-bind= "text: getTerm(FullName())"></p>
 <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- ko if: $index() !== "0" -->
            <!-- I think this is the line of code that is giving me trouble -->
        <!-- ko if: (getTerm(FullName()) != getTerm($parent.myclasses.Classes()[$index()-1].FullName)) -->
          <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:16px" data-bind= "text: getTerm(FullName())"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Javacript:

```
<script>
function getTerm(name) {
return name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' '));
 }
 function nameWithoutTerm(name) {
return name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + +1);
}
</script>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
 <ul class="myclasses-container" data-bind="foreach: myclasses.Classes">
 <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
<p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:16px" data-bind= "text: getTerm(FullName())"> W13</p>
 <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- ko if: $index() !== "0" -->
    <!-- ko if: (getTerm(FullName()) != getTerm($parent.myclasses.Classes()[$index()-1].FullName())) -->
    <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:16px" data-bind= "text: getTerm(FullName())"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

As you can see, all I am trying to do is loop through the array printing the semester if the previous one is not the same; however what is only displayed is 
  "W13" and not "W14" as well.

Comment: Can you provide your view model as well so we can see the "getTerm" function?

Comment: If you're trying to make a map or dictionary where the full name is the key, then instead of an array of objects, you should make an object, each property of which has the "FullName" as its name and the corresponding object (with the "Irrelevant Information") as the value.  For instance:

    var Classes = {
    "W13 Adv Cptr Architecture (CPHE-533-A)" : { /* some object */ },
    "W14 Adv Cptr Architecture (CPHE-521-A)" : { /* some object */ },
    //etc.
    };

(Sorry, I can't seem to get the code formatting right in a comment.)

Comment: @PatrickSteele Thanks, I completely forgot about that, I've added it in.

Comment: @DanKorn It doesn't appear as I have control over that, it's someone else's "knockout" framework and I am limited to what they have implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrick Steele stated, you need to add parenthesis to `FullName` if it is an observable.

But here is another problem. In your first check, you compare `$index()` with `0`, which seems fine.

The problem is on your second check, you compare to `"0"` instead of `0`, and as you use `!==` the comparison returns always true.

So it fails on the first loop, because after the check, you try to access item number `$index()-1` with `$index()` returning 0 meaning you are trying to reach item number `-1`!

Replace

```
<!-- ko if: $index() !== "0" -->
```

With

```
<!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In your compare, try changing:

```
getTerm($parent.myclasses.Classes()[$index()-1].FullName)
```

to:

```
getTerm($parent.myclasses.Classes()[$index()-1].FullName())
```

You need to add the parenthesis to FullName so it calls the observable to obtain the value.  You did it on the left side but missed it on the right.

Comment: I've done the changes however, nothing appears to have changed. I'm editing the top comment to include the HTML that is rendered